Why is my R Markdown HTML document not getting saved?
I have a data table with different vegetation anomaly surfaces (surface) (remote sensing) which are classified according to different region names (Nom) and anomaly classes (class).
I would like my html document produced with Rmarkdown :

have a search bar

in which you can select a region (Nom)

when the region is selected, a graph of the surface area by anomaly class would be produced using ggplot


Here's what I tested :
---
title: "Interactive Vegetation Anomaly Report with Custom CSS"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

chooseCRANmirror(ind = 1)  # Selects the first mirror in the list displayed


library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

anomalies_by_dept <- data.frame(
  Nom = c("AIN", "AIN", "AIN", "AIN", "HAUTE-SAVOIE", "HAUTE-SAVOIE", "HAUTE-SAVOIE", "HAUTE-SAVOIE", "SAVOIE", "SAVOIE", "SAVOIE", "SAVOIE"),
  class = c("1-Anomalie faible", "2-Anomalie moyenne", "3-Anomalie forte", "Bare ground", "1-Anomalie faible", "2-Anomalie moyenne", "3-Anomalie forte", "Bare ground", "1-Anomalie faible", "2-Anomalie moyenne", "3-Anomalie forte", "Bare ground"),
  surface = c(1935.2, 1470.8, 1104.9, 1245.4, 2153.9, 676.6, 1169.5, 948.9, 2.4, 1.3, 1.4, 0.7))

# User interfacer (UI)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Analyse des Anomalies de Végétation par Département"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      shiny::selectInput("selected_dept", "Choisir un département", choices = unique(anomalies_by_dept$Nom))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("anomalies_plot")
    )
  )
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$anomalies_plot <- renderPlot({
    selected_data <- anomalies_by_dept %>% dplyr::filter(Nom == input$selected_dept)
    
    ggplot(selected_data, aes(x = class, y = surface, fill = class)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
      labs(title = paste("Surfaces des Anomalies par Classe pour le Département de", input$selected_dept),
           x = "Classe d'Anomalie",
           y = "Surface (hectares)") +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
  })
}

# Launch the Shiny application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

The thing is, it's working in the "Viewer" of Rstudio but the document is not saved and Rstudio continues to run ('render')
|............                                        |  22% [setup]          

processing file: bilan_Fordead.Rmd
                                                                                                            
output file: C:/Users/camille.bernard/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpcBbPtU/file17f836ff733a/bilan_Fordead.knit.md

"C:/Program Files/RStudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS "C:\Users\camille.bernard\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcBbPtU\file17f836ff733a\bilan_Fordead.knit.md" --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output pandoc17f836263746.html --lua-filter "C:\Users\camille.bernard\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:\Users\camille.bernard\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\latex-div.lua" --variable bs3=TRUE --standalone --section-divs --template "C:\Users\camille.bernard\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html" --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --id-prefix section- --variable theme=bootstrap --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url=https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" --include-before-body "O:\Donnees_cartographiques\Teledetection\Surface_FORDEAD\header2.html" --include-after-body "O:\Donnees_cartographiques\Teledetection\Surface_FORDEAD\footer.html" 

Output created: C:/Users/camille.bernard/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpcBbPtU/file17f836ff733a/bilan_Fordead.html


This is clear because when you useruntime: shiny you run a server behind the document. In particular run ('render') are no synonyms here. You can't save this code into a static document.

I am voting to close this question because this is expected behavior.

See also this question, maybe you could do something similar.

those locations look like temp file locations, would you be able to use another machine to render this document?
